# Are there roles for non-bridge crew characters?

Tags: character-creation, star-trek-adventures

I am helping to develop a campaign for **Star Trek Adventures**. This campaign would focus on several new recruits on their first assignment (all ensign or non-commissioned). None of them would be bridge crew. Rather, they would be more rank-and-file members on a smaller ship who would progress to bridge crew throughout the campaign.

One of the last steps in character creation is to choose a role. The roles listed in the core rules are all bridge officers - people who generally have considerable experience already. Are there roles somewhere that are more appropriate to non-bridge crew?

Comment: @Quentin or indigochild: I've started a bounty to encourage one/both of you (or another user) to post an answer to this question, even if you're not sure it's the best possible answer yet. Once an answer is posted, people can suggest how it could be improved, or information it's missing. :)

Comment: Plus, if you post answers, we can vote on them, providing people who read them with a metric as to their quality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Just Skip Roles

Roles are described on pgs. 126-127 of the core rulebook. The sidebar on page 126 says:

> If the game being run is not focused on the senior staff of a starship, then choosing roles doesn't make sense. The Gamemaster may choose to skip that part entirely, or devise alternative roles more suited to the style of game being run.

In practice, my table skipped roles entirely. The game wasn't noticeably hampered, and the slight simplification probably helped our table of players, none of who had ever played a 2d20 game.

---

<sub>Thanks to the [quentin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/277/quentin) for originally recommending this in a comment.</sub>